# How to connect this SQL queries into one query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, google-maps

I'm using Google Maps API to create route between 2 points. I have some points in my database, and I want to find only that ones who are in 'distance' from road. It works, but I've used foreach point of route mysqlQuery, and e.g for one road I have 327 queries( it will kill my Database, so I have to deacrease it )

```
$query = sprintf("
    SELECT 
        id, address, name, 
        lat, lng, 
        ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians('%s') ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lng ) - radians('%s') ) + sin( radians('%s') ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) AS distance 
    FROM markers1 
    WHERE status > 0 
    HAVING distance < '%s' 
    ORDER BY distance LIMIT 0 , 20",

mysql_real_escape_string($center_lat),
mysql_real_escape_string($center_lng),
mysql_real_escape_string($center_lat),
mysql_real_escape_string($radius));
```

Does anyone have idea how to decrease it?

Best Regards,
Mateusz

EDIT:

```
$radius = 12; //e.g
 /*
      $JSONdata have e.g array like:

      array(
            array( 15.003245,52.43246 ),
            array( 17.003245,45.48646 ),
            array( 11.003245,58.12246 )
           )

           Here are only 3 points, but on route I have usually more than 50

           */
 foreach( $JSONdata as $D ) {

      $center_lat = $D->nb;
      $center_lng = $D->ob;

         $query = sprintf("

    SELECT 
        id, address, name, 
        lat, lng, 
        ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians('%s') ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lng ) - radians('%s') ) + sin( radians('%s') ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) AS distance 
    FROM markers1 
    WHERE status > 0 
    HAVING distance < '%s' 
    ORDER BY distance LIMIT 0 , 20",

     mysql_real_escape_string($center_lat),
     mysql_real_escape_string($center_lng),
     mysql_real_escape_string($center_lat),
     mysql_real_escape_string($radius));

     $result = mysql_query($query);
     $Queries++;

     while ($row = @mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){

        $Results[ $row['id'] ] = $row;

     }
}
```

Comment: Don't understand the question. You mention hundreds of queries but you what you provided is just one.

Comment: All of them are the same but with different variables

Comment: I don't understand the question. You have a single set of coordinates for a road and want to retrieve everything within in certain distance?

Comment: Different coordinates, And Want only that ones who are close to route

Comment: which distance is close? and why don't you describe better what you want?

Comment: $radius is e.g 2 miles. I want every point which is in range of road. It is something like this: http://maps2.bp.com/?country=uk&site=co&language=en . Create route from, to and it will show you only the closest stations to the road

Comment: you're showing us a working SQL-statement and you're writing you have a problem with calling this statement very often in an foreach clause. why don't you post your php code where you call the sql? without it is hardly possible to give you an answer.

Comment: I have edited post with PHP code